# Redirect a domain to a domain that doesn't meet community standard Facebook

Tags: facebook, web, redirect

So for some some reason my domain gayabalivisa.com doesn't follow the Community Standard of Facebook.

So I can not share links on facebook feeds I can not add my website in the bio and I can not send link of my website throw Messanger.

Facebook is not really helpful with the issue, I have tried the debugger Facebook tools several times and pointed out that the domain do follow community standard.

So I was thinking to solve the problem, I could add a new domain that will point to the domain gayabalivisa.com. Will I be able to share links on facebook with the new domain that redirects to gayabalivisa.com?

Thank you so much for your help!
Gabriele

Comment: That’ll very much depend on how you implement that redirect. If you do it via HTTP, then you’ll need to implement an exception for the Facebook scraper. Client-side JavaScript would be another option, the scraper does not care about that. And if you want “proper looking” shares, i.e. with title, description and thumbnail set according to your wishes, then your new “alternative domain” would have to return all the correct OG meta data.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your explanation! Do you have any tutorial for both methods using wordpress? I will appreciate, that